# Issue when scheduling tasks using clock() function

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, precision, clock

I would like to schedule tasks at different time intervals: at 0.1 sec, 0.9s .... 2s etc 
I use the clock() C++ function that returns the number of ticks since the beginning of the simulation and I convert the ticks number to seconds using CLOCKS_PER_SEC but I have noticed that the task isn't scheduled when the instant is a float, but when it's an integer it does. Here the portion of the code responsible for the scheduling:

```
float goal = (float) clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC + 0.4 ;  // initially (float) clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 0 ; 
if ((float) clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC == goal) 
     do stuff ;
```

In that case, it doesn't work, but when I schedule the task to be done in 3 seconds for instance it works. Is it a problem of precision??

Comment: If you want to use less than second resolution, then `clock` is not a good function to use. I would rather recommend `gettimeofday` instead.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `==` here. What happens if for some reason your process gets put to sleep for just long enough to miss your `goal`? Probably should use `>=` or `>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I can't use > or >= cause I have to schedule the task exactly at this time.

Comment: note: [clock() might ignore a process sleep time or time of its children](http://ideone.com/iEjgi)

Comment: you could use [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://gist.github.com/3296666). See [Making a Timer in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5774627/4279)

Comment: the clock() function returns the time your process have spent using the CPU. Except on windows, where clock() returns the wall clock time.

Answer (score 14):

If I was to implement some timer mechanism in C++, I would probably be using the [`std::chrono` namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) together with [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <sys/time.h>  // for `time_t` and `struct timeval`

namespace events
{
    struct event
    {
        typedef std::function<void()> callback_type;
        typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_type;

        event(const callback_type &cb, const time_type &when)
            : callback_(cb), when_(when)
            { }

        void operator()() const
            { callback_(); }

        callback_type callback_;
        time_type     when_;
    };

    struct event_less : public std::less<event>
    {
        bool operator()(const event &e1, const event &e2) const
        {
            return (e2.when_ < e1.when_);
        }
    };

    std::priority_queue<event, std::vector<event>, event_less> event_queue;

    void add(const event::callback_type &cb, const time_t &when)
    {
        auto real_when = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(when);

        event_queue.emplace(cb, real_when);
    }

    void add(const event::callback_type &cb, const timeval &when)
    {
        auto real_when = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(when.tv_sec) +
                         std::chrono::microseconds(when.tv_usec);

        event_queue.emplace(cb, real_when);
    }

    void add(const event::callback_type &cb,
             const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> &when)
    {
        event_queue.emplace(cb, when);
    }

    void timer()
    {
        event::time_type now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        while (!event_queue.empty() &&
               (event_queue.top().when_ < now))
        {
            event_queue.top()();
            event_queue.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

To use, simply add events using `events::add`, and call `events::timer` a few times every second.

Simple **example**:

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "hello from foo\n";
}

void done()
{
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
}

struct bar
{
    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from bar::hello\n";
    }
};

auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
bar b;

events::add(foo, now + std::chrono::seconds(2));

events::add(std::bind(&bar::hello, b), now + std::chrono::seconds(4));

events::add(done, now + std::chrono::seconds(6));

while (true)
{
    usleep(10000);  // TODO: Do some "real" work here instead...
    events::timer();
}
```

The above example will print:

```
hello from foo
hello from bar::hello
Done!
```

One line will be printed every two second. After `"Done!"` the program will just loop forever, doing nothing.

Note that this program contains lots of C++11 functionality, but has been tested with GCC 4.4.5 and 4.7.1. VC++2010 unfortunately does not have the `<chrono>` header, but the VC++2012RC apparently have it.

Comment: note: ["POSIX.1-2008  marks  gettimeofday()  as  obsolete,  recommending  the  use of  clock_gettime(2) instead."](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well, tomorrow when I have time I will convert it to use `std::chrono` instead. :)

Comment: This is nice but it seems like the granularity of the timer--how often checks for updates--should be part of the events namespace, or perhaps the whole thing should be encapsulated in a class.

Comment: This implementation basically polls constantly, using the CPU the whole time to execute code in between actual timeout events.  It's valid, but there are other ways that don't require polling.

Answer (score 0):

CLOCKS_PER_SEC is integer in your system. in other systems, it could be float too. put (float) near it too

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case it's an integer equal to 1000000

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because of your floating point comparison. This can provide unexpected results. Please avoid this.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) link