# C++ Call A Function After Time or Cancel

Tags: c++, timeout, countdown

I'm looking for a simple cross platform way to call a function after a certain amount of time with the option of killing it early.

Similar to how javascript works with `time = window.setTimeout("alert('Hello');", 500);` and `if(time) clearTimeout(time)`

Is this possible in basic C++ without any additional (non standard) libraries or framework?
If so can you give me a pointer in the right direction?

--

The reason I am doing this is I have a DB query that takes 3/4 seconds the first few times and display a wait cursor for this, however it looks a little silly/distracting after the query is cached and the cursor blinks to wait and then blinks back to normal!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I made a simple timer-event queue a for another question, you can look if it's something you can use. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866539/440558

Comment: You asked for a "cross-platform" solution, but you don't want to use any libraries aside from the "C++" standard, but your real issue is with the blinking of a wait cursor?  What specifically is your target platform?  What are you using for GUI development (Win32, wxWindows, QT)?  On Windows/Linux/Other?

Comment: GUI for Windows and in some cases Unix. Why i mention the libraries is as it's part of someone else's project and i can't change the way it works or bloat it.

Comment: C++11 available, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a function is a blocking operation. I can think of a couple ways to approximate the behavior you want...

**Time Slicing:**
Make the function execute a short segment of work which furthers it's overall goal incrementally. You can call it repeatedly until x time has passed.

**Multithreading:**
Run the function in another thread. But, to synchronize the results of the function between threads may take understanding of multithreading you don't have. If you really wanted to kill the operation after a certain duration you could forcibly shutdown the thread - but you probably don't want to do that. You probably want to let it finish, whenever it finishes (it won't be blocking the main thread so it shouldn't annoy the user).

The GUI library you're using may make the later option easy, but I don't know what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to span a thread, with the function to be executed, a mutex, a cancel flag and a timeout. The thread function would take all this parameters, sleep for the given timeout, locks the mutex and checks the flag. If the flag is not set, the function to be executed would be called.

If the function has to be canceled, the mutex must be locked, while setting the cancel flag.

As the handling of the thread arguments could become complex, I would but them all together into a structure, allocate the structure dynamically and keep on instance or a shared_ptr to the structure at the place where I might cancel the function call and pass one shared_ptr to the thread function.