# C++11 way to create a timer that can be "stopped" if needed

Tags: c++11

I have to call a function every X seconds to show the progress of a long running function, but i want to drop the notification if the function ends before the next tick of the progress update. I just recently started using C++11 and i don't know if there is a way to achieve this using proper c++11 syntax/objects.

Basically, I am trying to figure out if there is a way to access the same features as those exposed by the posix functions [timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and [timer_delete](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_delete.2.html) using the C++11 threads and async functions.

I did find this question "[How to create timer events using C++ 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650885/how-to-create-timer-events-using-c-11)", which covers almost everything i need but i couldn't figure out if there's a way to stop the async call once it is "submitted".

Is this possible now in C++11?

Comment: Maybe a timed lock, e.g. [`condition_variable::wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for)?

Answer (score 6):

#### Introduction

The simple solution is to make it so that the timer set to execute *f* in *N* *time-units* can *potentially sleep* for *N* *time-units*, but if something interrupts the sleep we should not execute the task *f*.

The usage of **[std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)** can solve this issue with ease, relying on the member-function [*wait_for*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for). This function will return *false* if the function didn't receive an interrupt, and *true* if it did.

<sub>*pending sample implementation*</sub>

Comment: Is there no interruptible sleep?  In most APIs, this is accomplished via waiting for the cancellation event with a timeout equal to the desired sleep interval.

Comment: @BenVoigt ah good point, of course `std::condition_variable::wait_for` can be used in this way, set it to sleep for *N* *time-units*, if interrupted; don't execute task. I'll write a sample implementation to add to the answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt IIRC `boost::thread` supports this, but not `std::thread`

Comment: I see your point and I guess it certainly will work. What i don't like is that this is similar to a busy waiting loop (of course, is a lot lighter because you will be sleeping most of the time) and i have to actually write the logic for the timer to keep working or stop. I liked the timer_create/timer_delete api because i delegate completely the timer implementation/interruption to the timer itself. Although, maybe i'm being just too lazy :P

Comment: The overload of `condition_variable::wait_for` that returns a `bool` takes a Predicate, and returns the result of this predicate. The other overload w/o predicate doesn't ignore spurious unblocking.

Comment: [Sample implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8804fee86d99a1e5 "Live at Coliru").

Comment: @Casey I'm currently on my phone, had to rush out the house before I had the chance to post my sample implementation. As soon as I'm at a computer I'll add it. /F

Comment: @Casey Why not `wait_for`?

Comment: @dyp to keep the intervals constant(-ish) regardless of the processing time for the function and queueing delay from the OS.

Comment: @Casey [According to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for), this should be what `wait_for` does. -- Btw, you should have compiled that with CLANG ;)

Comment: @dyp It depends whether you want your function to execute every X seconds, or have a delay of X seconds between the completion and initiation of function calls. I think the "every X seconds" semantic is more generally applicable (proof left to the reader).