# Call a class member function at periodic time intervals in c++11

Tags: multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013, timer

Let's have a class, which creates a thread and let run an infinite loop checking a que. In this thread, I would like to call periodically a function of the class (to process accumulated data from the que, for instance each 100 ms).

I've assembled a timer based on aswers
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14665230/1699328 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21058232
However, I do not know, how to call a function from the object, which created the thread. The timer is bellow:

```
#include <thread>

class TimerSimpleInfinite
{
public:
    template <class callable, class... arguments>
    TimerSimpleInfinite(int interval, callable&& f, arguments&&... args)
    {
        std::function<typename std::result_of<callable(arguments...)>::type()> task(std::bind(std::forward<callable>(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...));

        execute = true;
        std::thread([this, interval, task]() 
        {
            while (execute)
            {
                task();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
            }
        }).detach();

    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        execute = false;
    }

private:
    bool execute;
};
```

The idea I would like to achieve is to call the member class function like in the following snippet:

```
    // separated thread
    void Processor::Run()
    {
        // start timer - call member class function every 100 ms
        Timer timer(100, this, &Processor::EvaluateData);

        Data datata;
        while (sharedQueData.Dequeue(data))
        {
            // preprocess data...

            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            mVector.insert(data);
        }
    }

    // member class function to be called every 100 ms by timer
    void Processor::EvaluateData()
    {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
       // do anything with mVector
    }
```

The program has to be compiled by VS 2013.

Comment: Why don't you use a message queue, like [tbb::concurrent_queue<>](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm)? I mean processing the message queue without polling.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Because the data in vector are based on time and I do not want to evaluate them immediately when they arrive... (see introduction).

Nevertheless, this could work:
`template <class Callable, class Object, class... Args>
 Timer(int interval, Callable&& f, Object&& o, Args&&... args)
 {
  std::function<void()> task(std::bind(std::forward<Callable>(f), std::forward<Object>(o), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
`

But, Is there a way to deduce type by std::result_of in std::function?

Comment: I am not sure why you deduce the result type. You do not use it, do you?

Comment: Not now, but who knows ;-) and I want to know, if it is possible.
BTW Do I need to `std::forward` the object as in comment above? I am not STL expert yet...

Comment: What you have looks like a worker thread. Worker threads normally ignore  work item / task return values. You should accept the task as `std::function<void()>` and let the user decide what to initialize it with (lambda, bind expression, etc..).