# Is there any built-in functionality in c++ to run task at scheduled time

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any built-in functionality in c++ to run task at scheduled time? (Some thing like cron?) Or have I to implement it myself?

Comment: Using `this_thread::sleep_for` and `system_clock::now` it is possible to implement in a few lines.

Comment: Define "task". Are you talking about a process or a thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14665230/1870760 might come in useful.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can do is to wait on a mutex or other synchonization primitive for a specified period of time.

"Release" the mutex (or fire a condition variable, etc) if the app is told to shut down (always a good plan), and if it times out, otherwise run the task.

Note that there are no realtime guarantees -- wait in C++ waits "at least that long".  Basically, if the system is busy, tough.

This can be done in a thread, naturally, so whatever main functionality (message pump or whatever) isn't bothered by it.

You can also sleep for a specified period of time, but programs should always have an abort possibility, and sleeping doesn't provide it.