# Making a timer that executes a function after a certain amount of time in milliseconds

Tags: c++, timer

Let's say I have this function:

```
void changeMap(Player* player, int map) {
      player->setMap(map);
}
```

And I want a timer class that enables me to run that function after a certain amount of time, Something like this.

```
Player* chr;
int mapid = 300;
int milliseconds = 6000;

Timer.Schedule(changeMap(chr, 300), milliseconds);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of C++ standard (C++2011?) are you using. On which operating system? Consider using libraries like [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/) or [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/).

Comment: They're called "functions", not "voids". The `void` in the declaration means that it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I made a simple timer-event-queue [in this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866539/440558). Just put the event-pumping loop in a separate thread, and with shorter sleep. Note: C++11 only.

Comment: Timer? Schedule? You seem to be using a framework of some sort, C++ has no native timer support as far as I know. In fact, this almost looks like C# to me.

Comment: And I would initialize the `chr` pointer, perhaps to `nullptr` .... Don't forget to enable all warnings and debugging info in your C++ compiler (with GCC, compile with `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium The Timer.Schedule was an example for how I want it to work like.

Comment: Do you need your program to do other things while that timer is pending?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm using C++ 2008 .NET, Windows 7.

Comment: @aschepler Indeed. It's a game server, so yeah.

Comment: Such things are not fully standardized in C++. You want to use some library (I suggested two but you'll find more). And your question is *operating system specific* and you did not tell on which OS you want your code to run.

Comment: @FightRay: please edit your question to add appropriate tags.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Since it's a game server, It should run in my computer only.. At least for now. Whether it will work on other OS' or not doesn't concern me.

Comment: It very probably won't run on Linux or FreeBSD or GNU/Hurd or MacOSX. So your question is OS specific and you should tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a game loop then one way is to keep of list of events that you want to happen some time in the future where you store a time and a pointer to the function you want to call. (Or a std::function, or whatever). Keep the list sorted by time so the soonest event is a the top of the list.

Then in your main game loop, every loop, check the top of the list to see if the time of that event has been reached yet and if it has pop the event and call the function.

Comment: That won't work, since I need functions to be timed constantly. If a player has a changeMap schedule for the next 5 seconds, and many others also have it in a close timespan then they have to work in separated threads. Everytime I run something like Timer.Schedule(void(player), milliseconds) I need it to be able to be used constantly all the time by all means.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect by the liberal use of Functor delegate objects and templates:

CAlarm.h

```
#ifndef CALARM_H
#define CALARM_H

#include "ADTtime.h"
#include "CStopwatch.h"

template<class FunctionObject>
class Alarm : public StopWatch {

public:

    Alarm(const FunctionObject& fn);
    Alarm(double tickTime, const FunctionObject& fn);

    virtual ~Alarm();

    FunctionObject Tick();

protected:
    FunctionObject _delegate;
    double _tickTime;

private:

};

template<class FunctionObject>
Alarm<FunctionObject>::Alarm(const FunctionObject& fn)
    : StopWatch(), _delegate(fn), _tickTime(1.0) { }

template<class FunctionObject>
Alarm<FunctionObject>::Alarm(double tickTime, const FunctionObject& fn)
    : StopWatch(), _delegate(fn), _tickTime(tickTime) { }

template<class FunctionObject>
Alarm<FunctionObject>::~Alarm() {
    if(_isRunning) Stop();
}

template<class FunctionObject>
FunctionObject Alarm<FunctionObject>::Tick() {
    if(IsRunning() == false) return _delegate;

    if(GetElapsedTimeInSeconds() >= _tickTime) {
        Reset();
        _delegate();
    }
    return _delegate;
}

#endif
```

CStopwatch.h

```
#ifndef CSTOPWATCH_H
#define CSTOPWATCH_H

#include "ADTtime.h"

class StopWatch : public ADTTime {

public:

    StopWatch();
    virtual ~StopWatch();

    void Start();
    void Restart();
    void Stop();
    void Reset();

    virtual void CalculateElapsedTime();

    virtual double GetElapsedTimeInSeconds();
    virtual double GetElapsedTimeInMilliseconds();

protected:

private:

};

#endif
```

CStopwatch.cpp

```
#include "CStopwatch.h"

StopWatch::StopWatch() : ADTTime() {
    /* DO NOTHING. ALL INITIALIZATION HAPPENS IN BASE CLASS */
}
StopWatch::~StopWatch() {
    _startTime = -1;
    _endTime = -1;
    _deltaTime = -1.0;
    _isRunning = false;
}

void StopWatch::Start() {
    if(_isRunning == true) return;
    _startTime = clock();
    _isRunning = true;
}
void StopWatch::Stop() {
    if(_isRunning == false) return;
    _isRunning = false;
    CalculateElapsedTime();
}
void StopWatch::Restart() {
    Reset();
    Start();
}
void StopWatch::Reset() {
    Stop();
    _startTime = 0;
    _endTime = 0;
    _deltaTime = 0.0;
}
void StopWatch::CalculateElapsedTime() {
    _endTime = clock();
    _deltaTime = difftime(_startTime, _endTime);
}

double StopWatch::GetElapsedTimeInSeconds() {
    CalculateElapsedTime();
    return -ADTTime::GetElapsedTimeInSeconds();
}
double StopWatch::GetElapsedTimeInMilliseconds() {
    CalculateElapsedTime();
    return -ADTTime::GetElapsedTimeInMilliseconds();
}
```

ADTTime.h

```
#ifndef ADTTIME_H
#define ADTTIME_H

#include <ctime>

class ADTTime {

public:

    clock_t GetStartTime() const;
    clock_t GetStartTime();

    double GetStartTimeInSeconds() const;
    double GetStartTimeInSeconds();

    clock_t GetEndTime() const;
    clock_t GetEndTime();

    double GetEndTimeInSeconds() const;
    double GetEndTimeInSeconds();

    virtual double GetElapsedTimeInSeconds();
    virtual double GetElapsedTimeInMilliseconds();

    virtual void CalculateElapsedTime()=0;

    bool IsRunning() const;
    bool IsRunning();

    virtual void Start()=0;
    virtual void Restart()=0;
    virtual void Stop()=0;
    virtual void Reset()=0;

    ADTTime();
    virtual ~ADTTime();

protected:

    bool _isRunning;
    clock_t _startTime;
    clock_t _endTime;
    double _deltaTime;

private:

};

#endif
```

CADTTime.cpp

```
#include "ADTtime.h"

clock_t ADTTime::GetStartTime() const {
    return _startTime;
}
clock_t ADTTime::GetStartTime() {
    return static_cast<const ADTTime&>(*this).GetStartTime();
}

double ADTTime::GetStartTimeInSeconds() const {
    return static_cast<double>((_startTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}
double ADTTime::GetStartTimeInSeconds() {
    return static_cast<const ADTTime&>(*this).GetStartTimeInSeconds();
}

clock_t ADTTime::GetEndTime() const {
    return _endTime;
}
clock_t ADTTime::GetEndTime() {
    return static_cast<const ADTTime&>(*this).GetEndTime();
}

double ADTTime::GetEndTimeInSeconds() const {
    return static_cast<double>((_endTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}
double ADTTime::GetEndTimeInSeconds() {
    return static_cast<const ADTTime&>(*this).GetEndTimeInSeconds();
}

double ADTTime::GetElapsedTimeInSeconds() {
    return _deltaTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
double ADTTime::GetElapsedTimeInMilliseconds() {
    return _deltaTime;
}

bool ADTTime::IsRunning() const {
    return _isRunning;
}
bool ADTTime::IsRunning() {
    return static_cast<const ADTTime&>(*this).IsRunning();
}

ADTTime::ADTTime() : _isRunning(false), _startTime(-1), _endTime(-1), _deltaTime(-1.0) { }

ADTTime::~ADTTime() {
    _isRunning = false;
    _startTime = -1;
    _endTime = -1;
    _deltaTime = -1.0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you provide those non-const member functions that just call the const overloads? (I.e. why not leave them away?)

Comment: @DyP It's to keep the code DRY and allows the calling of the methods on const and non-const objects. See `Effective C++, 3rd Edition by Scott Meyers Item 3, page 23-24`

Comment: Don't have the book to look up what Meyers' argument is, but you *can* call const-qualified member functions on non-const objects.

Comment: Meyers uses this pattern to call non-const accessor functions from const ones. His point is that you can cast away the const safely because you know you are actually not doing anything non-const. You use the const ones from non-const ones, which is pointless, as DyP pointed out.

Comment: So basically, All I have to do is use this function " Alarm(double tickTime, const FunctionObject& fn); " For my desire. Also, is the tick time in milliseconds?

Comment: @FightRay The tick time is in seconds. These classes were written before C++11 was released. I recommend switching to using the `chrono` library available in C++11 to get better granularity.

Comment: " player->disconnect() " is a void. When I try using " Alarm(10, player->disconnect()); " It throws an error saying " error C2955: 'Alarm' : use of class template requires template argument list "

Comment: @FightRay ` You must wrap player->disconnect() in a Functor Object. Provide its typename to the template parameter, and pass a copy of the object to Alarm. Possible implementation: `Alarm<FO>(10.0, FO(player))`.

Comment: Well, so if `player->disconnect()` is a void, What should I replace "FO" with? `Alarm<void>(10.0, void(player->disconnect()))` doesn't work.

Comment: @FightRay Asking to debug code in the comments is discouraged. At this point I'm going to suggest finding a tutorial or book that talks about template and Function Object implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running on Windows OS, I don't understand why are you reinventing the wheel?

```
    CComPtr<IReferenceClock> pReferenceClock;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SystemClock, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IReferenceClock, (void**)&pReferenceClock );

    hr = pReferenceClock->AdviseTime( ... );

    // or, hr = pReferenceClock->AdvisePeriodic( ... );
```

and once you are done,

```
hr = pReferenceClock->Unadvise( adviseCookie );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple (perhaps a bit rough around the edges) function that fire off a one-off event, like a timer, after a specified amount of milliseconds, using `std::thread` and `std::chrono` facilities

Something like that:

```
void doAfter( const std::function<void(void)>& f,
    size_t intervalMs )
{
    std::thread t{[f, intervalMs] () -> void
        {
            auto chronoInterval = std::chrono::milliseconds( intervalMs );
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( chronoInterval );
            f();
        }
    };
    // You can either `t.detach()` the thread, or wait to `join` it in main
}
```