# Implementing a timer in c++

Tags: c++

I am currently making a game in c++. I have below a timer function:

```
void timer(int &s , int &m , bool a)
{
   while (a)
   {
      Sleep(1000);
      if (s%60)
        m+=1;
      s+=1;
   }
}
```

Here is the function for the game:

```
void game()
{
   int s = 0 , m = 0;
   char a[]="Computers";
   char b[10];
   timer(s,m,true);
   while (strcmpi(a,b)!=0)
   {
      cout<<"Guess the word:";
      gets(b);
   }
   timer(s,m,false);
   cout<<"You got it correct!\n";
   cout<<"Time taken : "<<m<<':'<<s<<endl;
}
```

When I run the program , nothing happens. I am guessing the timer is running and not allowing the while loop in the `game()` to get executed.

So basically I am trying to find out the time the user takes to guess the word correctly.

How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your assumption is correct: the timer is running and not allowing the while loop in the game() to get executed.

Comment: When you say `timer in C++`, people expect `std::chrono` and all.

Comment: @Bastyen i am making it false later on in the program

Comment: Either use threads, or rewrite the timer function so it doesn't block but can be called periodically.

Comment: @MohitBhasi you will **never** reach "later on in the program"

Comment: @MohitBhasi how could you do that? it's passed by value

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thats exactly what i am looking for. How do i call the function periodically

Comment: For a non-threaded timer, you could check [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866539/440558). The main loop that does the sleeping in my answer, should be your main game loop. You can also make it threaded by putting the loop in a new [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: @MohitBhasi, your function `timer` will never return if the value of `a` is `true`. The value of `a` is never reset. Also, the values of `m` and `s` are updated but they are not used for anything else. The purpose of those arguments is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is the time taken, chuck your timer. Ask what time it is when the user starts, store it, and subtract the start time from the time when the user finishes.

```
void game()
{
   int s = 0 , m = 0;
   char a[]="Computers";
   char b[10];
   time_t start = time(NULL); <<<< Modification here
   while (strcmpi(a,b)!=0)
   {
      cout<<"Guess the word:";
      gets(b);
   }
   cout<<"You got it correct!\n";
   time _t taken = time(NULL) - start;
   m = taken / 60; <<<< Modification here
   s = taken % 60; <<<< Modification here
   cout<<"Time taken : "<< m <<':'<<s<<endl;
}
```

If allowed by the assignment, consider replacing `char`s a and b with `string`s a and b. The user cannot overflow the string and wreak havoc on your program the way they can with char arrays and `gets`.

```
void game()
{
   int s = 0 , m = 0;
   std::string a ="Computers"; <<<< Modification here
   std::string b; <<<< Modification here
   time_t start = time(NULL); 
   do
   {
      cout<<"Guess the word:";
      cin>> b; <<<< Modification here
   } while (a != b); <<<< Modification here. No sense testing b before you read b
   cout<<"You got it correct!\n";
   time _t taken = time(NULL) - start;
   m = taken / 60; 
   s = taken % 60; 
   cout<<"Time taken : "<< m <<':'<<s<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Had tried this before but i couldnt get it to work !

Comment: Could you explain why your are passing a NULL parameter to time()

Comment: Personal preference. You get the same time at a pointer or returned. With the returned value I can immediately use the time in calculations and don't have to have a temporary variable hanging around.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the chrono functions:

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

auto a = high_resolution_clock::now();

... what you want to measure ...

auto b = high_resolution_clock::now();

cout << "took " << duration_cast<seconds>(b - a).count() << " seconds" <<  endl;
```

Comment: Thanks but I am still a novice in C++ so would like to stick with the basics

Comment: Especially because you are a novice you should use the easy to use facilities like chrono, they are higher level, safer and more powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will block on `while(true)`. Please consider using [std::chrono](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

```
void game()
{
   int s = 0 , m = 0;
   char a[]="Computers";
   char b[10];
   auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
   while (strcmpi(a,b)!=0)
   {
      cout<<"Guess the word:";
      gets(b);
   }
   auto time_elapsed = chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
   cout<<"You got it correct!\n";
   cout<<"Time taken : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
                         (time_elapsed ).count() << " s"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but I am still a novice in c++

Answer (score 1):

You can use the time.h header file to measure time elapsed.Your code can b like this:

```
#include<time.h>
void game()
{ 
 int s = 0 , m = 0;
 char a[]="Computers";
 char b[10];
 clock_t start, end;
 double time_used;
// timer(s,m,true);  comment out this line
 start = clock();
 while (strcmpi(a,b)!=0)
  {
  cout<<"Guess the word:";
  gets(b);
  }
  end = clock();
 time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 timer(s,m,false);
 cout<<"You got it correct!\n";
 cout<<"Time taken : "<<time_used<<" seconds"<<endl;
```

}

For more information on time.h header file see this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm)