# C++11 chrono library - How to execute method after a specific time interval?

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I want to use properly the chrono library to configure my class to call a method, after some milliseconds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

Class House
{
private:
   //...
public:
   House() {};
   ~House() {};

   void method1() { std::cout << "method1 called" << std::endl; };
   void method2() { std::cout << "method2 called" << std::endl; };
   void method3() { std::cout << "method3 called" << std::endl; };
};

int main
{
   House h;

   //For the object 'h', I need to call method1() after 100ms
   // ???

   //For the object 'h', I need to call method2() after 200ms
   // ???

   //For the object 'h', I need to call method3() after 300ms
   // ???

   return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I've [made a simple timer event handler example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866539/440558) some time ago. Maybe it can help a little?

Comment: Chrono is a library for time, not for scheduling. Scheduling is hard.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg :) I think it will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a snippet from a book I have been reading / studying since I'm just getting into C++. (I started about 3 months ago but before that I practiced Java and Python a bit.) This explains how to do what you're intending to do as well as an example to show. I could have explained it in my own words; however I feel as if this hits the nail on the head:

> **5.3.4.1 Waiting for Events**
>
> Sometimes, a thread needs to wait for some kind of external event, such as another thread completing a task or a certain amount of time having passed. The simplest “event” is simply time passing. Consider:
>
> ```
> auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
> this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{20}); 
> auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
> cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << " nanoseconds passed\n";
> ```
>
> Note that I didn't even have to launch a thread; by default, this_thread refers to the one and only thread (§ 42.2.6). I used duration_cast to adjust the clock’s units to the nanoseconds I wanted. See § 5.4.1 and § 35.2 before trying anything more complicated than this with time. The time facilities are found in `<chrono>`.
>
> *— The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup*

I feel as if using this method would help accomplish what you're trying to do: accomplish tasks one after the other. Check out `<chrono>`. I found this answer because of a book I was reading, this isn't my work this is from a book. If you are intending on having many tasks running simultaneously, you will need to create threads and if they happen to share a resource, you will probably need locks or just use `unique_lock` / `lock_guard`. I prefer `unique_lock`.

Comment: This is a very naive and thus vulnerable approach. Since the code sample provided by OP is single threaded this is sufficient (given that the scheduling intervals are big enough not to suffer from timer precision), but in a multi threaded scenario this would be a catastrophe.

Comment: The example of this answer can simply wrapped in a lambda and sent to std::async and it would work fine.
Though in the long term you might wanna wrap it in a class that does that for you

Comment: @Rudolfs as you can tell, im still a noob;learning new things and fundementals everyday, but still a noob. Thank you for the input

Comment: @KABoissonneault I considered using the async example as well, do you think I should edit this and include it in there? i was just trying to show him a method that resembled closely the approach he was intending on taking.