# Sleep or wait that doesnt stop the whole program?

Tags: c++, timer, sdl, wait, sleep

So I'm pretty new with programming from scratch, have mainly used unity for a few years up untill now so my general programming knowledge is pretty good. Started studying game development at a university after summer though where we began programming from scratch and as a task we have to make a simple game in a 2D engine we made together in class.

So the game I decided to make was a copy of bomberman and I've gotten as far as where I'm now making the bombs functional.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to propperly add in a timer that counts down the time to where the bomb exlpode so the player can avoid it.

I've tried SDL_Delay and _sleep which both just pause the entire program so that doesn't work and I've searched around for more options but not really understood how things work. If I could get some expamples and links to pages that explains how to properly make something like this work (something easy and small hopfully :P) then that would be highly appreciated!

Note that we are using SDL in the engine.

Thanks!

Comment: Game engines should not really sleep very much, if at all. If you need to do a delay implement some kind of event queue so you can add an event X seconds (or milliseconds or whatever) in the future, and then poll this queue in the main event loop. Maybe something like I implemented in [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865460/issue-when-scheduling-tasks-using-clock-function/11866539#11866539)?

Comment: For each bomb take a note of the time it was set and then every frame check how long each bomb has been ticking?

Comment: Or... if your game runs in a constant frame rate, all you need is a counter as a "time reference" and if, say you run at 1000 frames/s and you want the bomb to explode after 1s, you would compare if(counter > deadline) ... with deadline having been set earlier as deadline = counter + 1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, a game uses a loop, in which you read user input (you are probably using `SDL_PollEvent` for that), advance the game state for a short time period and draw the screen. This loop is typically called the game loop, render loop or main loop.

A simple, accurate and typical way to delay an event (such as a timed explosion), is to store the future time into a queue. Then, each time the game state advances, check the first and therefore the oldest timestamp in the queue and if the current time is higher than the stored one, then we know that the the thing should now happen and you can call the function that executes the event without delay. Then remove the timestamp from the queue and check the next one until only future events remain or the queue is empty.

If the event delay can vary, then you'll need to use a priority queue to always get the event that should fire next.

skypjack points out in the comments that this is a problematic approach if you need to implement pausing the game. That can be solved by not measuring wall clock, but instead use a separate simulation time that drifts from the wall clock when the game is paused. They also propose a simpler solution:

> store a timeToEvent (to be elapsed) and decrement it, so that you detach the game time from the real one. Once it's <= 0, it's its time.

That approach is simpler, but has more overhead for checking the expiration of deadlines.

Comment: To store the future time does not goes along with a pause in the game (background on mobile?). This ends with all the bombs fired once you get out from the pause. Usually, it's better to store a timeToEvent (to be elapsed) and decrement it, so that you detach the game time from the real one. Once it's <= 0, it's its time.

Comment: @skypjack a problem with your approach is that you have to decrement the countdown for every incoming event, which doesn't scale well (O(n) complexity). Of course, that might not be a problem if there are only a few events at any given time. The problem that you describe can be avoided by using internal time that drifts from the wall clock when the game is paused.

Comment: Yeah, also the internal time is a good (even better) solution, anyway I guess that in bomberman he won't have a problem like scaling the other and far easier solution!! :-)

Comment: Anyway, I'd cite in the answer one of those approaches for the sake of completeness, that's all... Also, be aware that in any case you have a complexity of O(N), for you still have to check if the future time has been reached. Unless you decide to order those times, in such a case the problem is on the insert, and so on. Anyway, interesting and upvoted.

Comment: @skypjack I agree, your proposed solution is very simple and probably good enough for Elis. I shall mention it in my answer. Neither of our solutions might be necessary though, since Elis doesn't mention the requirement to support pausing. Good point in that the complexities of the solutions are the same but the O(N) of the timestamp solution is much less because the N is the number of events that have expired at the current time slice. You don't need to check the rest once you've found the first that's in the future. The N in the countdown is all future events in every time slice.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've said: if you plan to sort them during the insertion, you reduce the actual complexity for each cycle (well, it's still O(N) in the worst case, but it happens to be the case almost never), but you spend much more once you have to add a new item. You know, those solutions depend on the actual problems, there is not the *right* solution or the *best* one, that's why an answer that offers more than one approach is usually more interesting from my point of view. Thank you for your interesting comments, really appreciated. :-)

Comment: @skypjack ah, I skipped the rest of your comment. You don't need to sort the entire queue. A heap structure is enough, and quite typical for a priority queue. N being the number of events in the priority queue, the insertion is O(log N) for any individual insert in worst case and inserting N events is O(N), so constant per insertion in average. Even if you do keep the entire queue sorted, a balanced binary tree also gives O(log N) worst case insert.

Comment: I took an offense because you skipped my comment :-) anyway, you are right, thank you for the detailed response.