# C++ - How to make a simple timer and how would I go about using if statements based on it?

Tags: c++

Im making a sort of virtual pet. In a way Im copying the tamagochi.

```
// VirtualPetProjClassesandObjectsPRCT.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include "Vpet.h"

int main()
{
    // Set Name & General Info
    std::string pop;
    std::cout << "What would you like to call your pet?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> pop;
    std::cout << "List of commands you can do with " << pop << std::endl << "'state'" << std::endl << "'quit'" << std::endl << "'feed'." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "If you feed bob less than quarter his weight he will gain weight but still be hungry!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bob weighs 50 kgs!" << std::endl;

    VPet bob(50, false);
    bob.feedPet(5);
    do
    {
        //input
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;

        if (input == "Quit" || input == "quit")
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (input == "Feed" || input == "feed")
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the amount you would like to feed " << pop << " - ";
            int x;
            std::cin >> x;
            if (x > (bob.getWeight() * 0.5))
            {
                std::cout << "Bob can't eat that much!" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                bob.feedPet(x);
                std::cout << "You have fed " << pop << " " << x << " kgs of food!" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        // State
        if (input == "State" || input == "state")
        {
            std::cout << pop << " weighs: " << bob.getWeight() << std::endl;

            if (bob.getHungry())
            {
                std::cout << pop << " is hungry." << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << pop << " is not hungry." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    } while (0 != 1);
}
```

Ive created a class and some functions for feeding the pet, checking its weight and if hes hungry but I would also like to make a clock that every couple of minutes or seconds would check to see how much time has passed and if a certain amount has passed I would print that the virtual pet is hungry using a bool variable Ive defined earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Knowing about [the standard C++ date and time functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) would be a good start.

Comment: I'll make sure to read up on that allthough Im looking for a solution more because my class isn't going to study time functionality anytime soon.

Comment: How about something like [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11866539/440558)? There must be more and better tutorials by now though.

Comment: You'll need a timer facility. Although there isn't a portable one in the standard, you can build one from standard elements. See e.g. this blog post [Periodic Processing With Standard C++11 Facilities](https://bulldozer00.com/2013/12/27/periodic-processing-with-standard-c11-facilities/).

Comment: *"make a clock that every couple of minutes or seconds would check to see how much time has passed"* You don't need to check anything because if you check every couple of minutes or seconds then a couple of minutes or seconds will have passed. [`std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) lets you wait 2 seconds.

Comment: I'll try it really thank you for the help though!

Comment: @nwp I see! that helps me out a ton! thank you!

Comment: @AdiShavit I'll make sure to read on that too ^^

Comment: I don't like how the program asks to name the pet and then always calls it Bob anyways.

Comment: @nwp Originally the pet would be called bob but I decided to make it whatever the user would want, Bob is the name of the object, nothing more. If you run the program (with the header file and the other cpp that I made for the functions) it will always call the pet by the name of what the string pop is.

Comment: That's what I would expect, but I see `std::cout << "Bob weighs 50 kgs!" << std::endl;` which probably should have been `std::cout << pop << " weighs 50 kgs!\n";`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that! (in testing I always called vp "bob", thats just a slip up by me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library chrono to measure a timespan and then act accordingly.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main () { 
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    while (1) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

        // In your real code you will perhaps not need the sleep

        const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        const auto duration = now - start;
        if ( duration.count() > 2e9) {
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "waiting ..."  << std::endl;
    } 

    std::cout <<"done" << std::endl;
}
```

`time ./chrono_example` this output:

waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
waiting ...
done

real    0m2.013s

user    0m0.002s

sys 0m0.004s

Comment: Im sorry for this question but could you give me an example of wait 2 seconds then cout something? I just don't know how to use Chrono yet!

Answer (score 1):

In `main()`, a timer is created that allows a pet to be unfed for 5 seconds and checks if unfed every second. If more than 5 seconds passes before the last meal, the pet is fed and the time of feeding is recorded. The timer runs for 10 seconds and is then stopped as a demonstration.

For different durations, look at the [helper types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Helper_types) for `std::chrono::duration`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

class FeedTimer {
public:
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
    using Duration = std::chrono::seconds;

    FeedTimer(Duration limit, Duration tick) : alive(false),
                                               lastFed(Clock::now()),
                                               limit(limit),
                                               tickRate(tick) { }

    ~FeedTimer() {
        // If running, the thread is stopped when it is destroyed.
        if (alive) {
            stop();
        }
    }

    // Starts the timer.
    void start() {
        alive = true;
        thread = std::thread(&FeedTimer::update, this);
        std::cout << "Timer started.\n";
    }

    // Stops the timer.
    void stop() {
        alive = false;
        thread.join();
        std::cout << "Timer stopped.\n";
    }

    void update() {
        while (alive) {
            TimePoint now = Clock::now();

            // Determines if more time has passed than the allowed limit.
            if (now - lastFed > limit) {
                lastFed = now;
                std::cout << "Just fed the pet.\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "Pet is full.\n";
            }

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(tickRate);
        }
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> alive; // Thread stops when this is false.
    std::thread thread;
    TimePoint lastFed; // The last time the pet was fed.
    Duration limit; // Maximum amount of time the pet can go unfed.
    Duration tickRate; // Rate at which the timer runs.
};

int main() {
    FeedTimer timer = FeedTimer(std::chrono::seconds(5),
                                std::chrono::seconds(1));
    timer.start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    timer.stop();
}
```

You'll want to modify it so `VPet` can interact with it. One approach would be to `stop()` the timer once the pet is hungry and print a message to the user, wait until the user feeds the pet, set `lastFed` to `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`, and `start()` the timer again.