# Periodic timer implementation in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to implement a timer class which executes a callback periodically in a separate thread.
I am successful in implementing it but I am facing issue while trying to stop it.
I am a novice in threads,any help here would mean a lot.

I have a variable activate in timer class which can be set or reset for exiting the infinite loop of periodic method.

Please help me how to trigger the exit in the periodic thread by setting the value in main thread.

this is the timer class file

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __MyTimer_h__
#define __MyTimer_h__

template <typename Cback>
class MyTimer {
public:
    MyTimer() = delete;

    MyTimer(Cback M, int secs);

    MyTimer(const MyTimer& obj) = default;


    ~MyTimer();
    virtual void scheduler() = 0;
    void stopTimer();
    bool isActivated () const;
    int getDuration () const;
    Cback getCallback() const;
    void activateTimer();
    void deActivateTimer();
private:

    bool Activated;
    Cback callback;
    int duration;

};

template <typename Cback>
MyTimer<Cback>::MyTimer(Cback M, int secs) :callback{ M }, duration{ secs }, Activated{ false }
{
}

template <typename Cback>
void MyTimer<Cback>::stopTimer()
{
    Activated = false;
}

template <typename Cback>
bool MyTimer<Cback>::isActivated() const {
    return Activated;
}

template <typename Cback>
void MyTimer<Cback>::activateTimer() {
    Activated = true;
}

template <typename Cback>
void MyTimer<Cback>::deActivateTimer() {
    Activated = false;
}
template <typename Cback>
int MyTimer<Cback>::getDuration() const {
    return duration;
}

template <typename Cback>
Cback MyTimer<Cback>::getCallback() const {
    return callback;
}

template <typename Cback>
MyTimer<Cback>::~MyTimer()
{

}

#endif
```

This is the main class file

```
void callbackfunc() {
    cout << "callback function called at";
    printcurrenttime();

}
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "\nmain function called at";
    printcurrenttime();

    unique_ptr<MyTimer<function<void(void)>>> timer(new MyTimer< function<void(void)>>(callbackfunc, 2));
    timer->scheduler();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
    periodicpointer->stopTimer();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5)); // Allow time for threads to finish
    return 1;
}
```

I am using thread join in the scheduler so main is waiting till the execution of thread is complete. I have to find out a way to stop the periodic timer by calling method deactivate timer.
I can use condition variables and mutexes.but cannot come up with an exact solution,An expert help would help here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OT: Any symbol beginning with double underscore (like for example `__MyTimer_h__`) is *reserved* and should not be defined by you. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: As for the code you show, it should not even build. The `scheduler` function is abstract, you can't create instances of the `MyTimer` class.

Comment: As for the problem of timers in a thread, first of all you need to decide if you have a one-shot timer, which will run once and then exit; Or of it should be as recurring timer. For a one-shot timer I recommend a detached thread, where the thread function simply sleeps the required amount of time, calls the function and then exits.

Comment: For a recurring timer, the thread function have a loop where it sleeps a ***very*** short time, and compares timestamps when the callback function should be called. Exit the loop when the timer is asked to stop, and the "stop" call then joins the thread.

Comment: Another thing to be aware about for timers in threads: If they use shared data in any way, you need the normal thread-synchronization and protection mechanisms as any other thread. Otherwise you'll have data-races. This is because the callback function will run in the context of the timer thread.

Comment: And unless this is for a class or school assignment, or similar, don't make up your own timer. Use the timer functionality that's native to the OS you're targeting. Those will be much better, and will work in a much better way, and make sure there's no weird context or threads or synchronization needed.

Comment: Lastly, for a more event-loop based timer implementation (which can be put into a thread) I shamelessly offer [my own implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865460/issue-when-scheduling-tasks-using-clock-function/11866539#11866539) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Common idiom for run task in separate thread.

- create context that can access by multiple threads.
- run context in independent thread and block that thread util all task done.
- don't forget to protect resource that can access by multiple threads.
- make it's simple, readable if possible.

here my idea that I inspire from asio library and this [pdf](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2017-01-18-concurrency/2017-01-18-concurrency.pdf). This might be bug somewhere. please be careful.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

template <typename F , typename D = std::chrono::seconds>
struct TimerContext{
    using func_type = F;
    using duration_type = D;
    TimerContext(func_type in_func,duration_type in_interval):
        func{in_func}, interval{in_interval}, done{false}, is_stop{true}
    {}
    ~TimerContext(){
        std::cout << "quit\n";
    }
    void run(){
         while(!done){
            run_task();
         }
    }
    void start(){
        std::cout << "start\n";
        is_stop = false;
    }
    void stop(){
        std::cout << "stop\n";
        is_stop = true;
    }
    void im_done(){
       done = true;
    }
private:
    void run_task(){
       while(!is_stop && !done){
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
       }
    }
    func_type func;
    duration_type interval;
    std::atomic<bool> done; 
    std::atomic<bool> is_stop; //protect both done and is_stop because they're able to access by multiple threads
};

template <typename C = std::chrono::system_clock>
struct CallBack{
    using clock_type = C;
    int i = 1;
    std::chrono::time_point<clock_type> prev;
    void operator()(){
        auto now =  clock_type::now();
        std::cout << "run #" << i;
        if(i > 1){
            std::cout << " diff " <<  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - prev).count() << "ms" ;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        prev = now;
        i++;
    }
};
int main(){
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    using cb_type = std::function<void()>;
    
    TimerContext tc{CallBack{}, 0.5s};
    std::thread th{[&tc](){ 
        tc.run(); //block for make thread alive
    }};
    th.detach(); //let thread run independently

    tc.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s); //do other thing

    tc.stop();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); //do other thing

    tc.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); //do other thing

    tc.im_done();

    std::cout << "done all thread\n";

    return 0;
}
```